How will variables be rendered that weren't declared?
I am trying some Spring MVC stuff, and the template engine is Thymeleaf.
In my view, there is
<p th:text="${message}"></p>

But when first accessing to this view, the message attribute hasnt been added to the model passed from the controller.
I found there is no error for the rendering. By inspecting, there is only <p></p>
It seems Thymeleaf just leaves it blank.
Is it the default behavior for thymeleaf for the variable expression hasnt been added to the model?

Related: How to throw exception is template variable not found in Context? - So the answer seems to be Yes.

@DarkBee Thanks for the reference. Can u make it an answer?
Or If you/anyone can find some quotes about this behavior from the official documentation, please add it to the answer.

I don't have an official source to back the answer up, I'm only assuming on what I've found on Stack

This is normal behaviour. See this comment from Daniel Fernandez (Author of Thymeleaf):

...there is no exception being thrown when the username variable does not exist in the context...


Thanks for your reference, so the default behavior is just leave it blank, right?
